# setInterval() wait time is after the previous one was called or after it was done? / how to control waiting time between loop iteration?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use setInterval to call an API that has rate limit for requests per seconds.
I tried to use setInterval as a while loop, but I can't find info on when it starts the next round.

So if I do:

```
setInterval(() => {
    CallAPI();
    // Some proccessing
}, 300)
```

Will the next round start after the first one finishes or regardless of it? because order matter, and also timing can cause an error.

I can also try to do the same with setTimeout and a while loop like so:

```
while(true) {
setTimeout(() => {
    CallAPI();
    // do some proccessing
}), 300
}
```

But again, I am not sure when the next round of the loop will start.

And lastly I cheat my way through it and do

```
while(true) {
    await CallAPI();
    // Do proccessing
    await setTimeout(() => true, 300)
}
```

So what is the order for setTimeout() and setInterval() in a loop?

Comment: 1st example: The next `setInterval` will occur in ~300ms regardless of anything else. 2nd example: Much, much worse; you're creating timeouts as fast as the browser allows. 3rd example: `setTimeout` isn't awaitable, you're calling `CallAPI` immediately after it completes and the `setTimeout` is basically a no-op created every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call it when it is done executing. No need for a loop.

```js
function fakeCall () {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    window.setTimeout(resolve, Math.random() * 2);
  });
}



function next() {
  window.setTimeout( async function () {
    await fakeCall();
    console.log(Date.now());
    next();
  }, 3000);
}

next();
```

Comment: I was hoping there is a more elegant solution than recursion. Ty for your help, hope some day they'll add this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to set up your loop as follows:

```js
var TO_asyncLoop = null;
function asyncLoop(fn, ms){
  clearTimeout(TO_asyncLoop);
  TO_asyncLoop = setTimeout(() => { fn() }, ms)
}

var i = 0;
function doSomething(){
  // do somthing
  console.log("hi", i++);

  // when this "something" is finished, do it again:
  asyncLoop(doSomething, 500)
}

doSomething()
```

Comment: Curious why the `clearTimeout`; seems superfluous since the timer will already have fired.

Comment: good practice, if the "asyncLoop" gets called too fast, or by some unknown process, it wont jumble things up... keeps things running in series (not parallel).

Comment: If `asyncLoop` gets called too fast the old timeouts won’t get cleared anyway; the timer ref would be overwritten—at best you’d be able to stop a single “overrun”. That’s why the general pattern is to only call the (potentially) long-running process at the end of timer expiry (see Eric’s answer).